# extract values from sql response

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently putting together a panda dataframe. For this, I query my sql to prepare the data.

```
    mycursor.execute("select post_id,meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'berufsgruppe' and post_id = %s",[id])
df_berufsgruppe=pd.DataFrame(data=mycursor.fetchall(), columns=['post_id','berufsgruppe'])
```

The following values are contained in the sql in a few places. What do I have to do to get the values?

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10: "employed";}
a:1:{i:0;s:5:"Miete";}
a:1:{i:0;s:2:"ja";}
```

I need "employed

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: `a:1:{i:0;s:10: "employed";} [...]` is your dataframe `df_berufsgruppe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `df` look like this?

```
                  berufsgruppe
0  a:1:{i:0;s:10: "employed";}
1       a:1:{i:0;s:5:"Miete";}
2          a:1:{i:0;s:2:"ja";}
```

If so then you could extract the values using `.str.extract()`.

```
df['value'] = df['berufsgruppe'].str.extract(r'.+"(.+)".+')
print(df)

                  berufsgruppe     value
0  a:1:{i:0;s:10: "employed";}  employed
1       a:1:{i:0;s:5:"Miete";}     Miete
2          a:1:{i:0;s:2:"ja";}        ja
```